# Another way to get to the element instead of xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

[image]

I want to extract data ["Over/Under +0.5", "1.04", "11.46", "95.3%"] by using python(selenium) for more than 10 pages but I have a problem with getting the exact value with Xpath inside the table the number inside div[] change in each web page
is there any way to get to the same value inside the table?
for example :
page1

'//*[@id="odds-data-table"]/div[12]/div/strong'

page2

'//*[@id="odds-data-table"]/div[11]/div/strong'

https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league-2017-2018/newcastle-utd-arsenal-vLKS6e2j/?r=1#over-under;2

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Posting a link to the page you're trying to get the data from and exactly which data you're trying to get would allow someone to assist better. Are you basically trying to extract the entire table here? So you can get the data in a format like `["Over/Under +0.5", "1.04", "11.46", "95.3%"]`?

Comment: https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league-2017-2018/newcastle-utd-arsenal-vLKS6e2j/?r=1#over-under;2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following XPath should work :

```
//div[@class="table-header-light odd first"]//*[contains(text(),".")][not(parent::strong)]
```

Output : 3 nodes > Over/Under/Payout

If you want to keep the "Over/Under +0.5" element :

```
//div[@class="table-header-light odd first"]//*[contains(text(),".")]
```

or

```
(//div[@class="table-header-light odd first"]//text())[position()<=4]
```

Output : 4 nodes